# Java File Update

Tags: java, file

How to change the part of content of the file, starting at specific character, without reading and writing whole file?

Comment: do you know how to do it in C (fseek())?  Have you looked at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java.io.RandomAccessFile` class. You can `seek()` to an arbitrary position in the file and then read or write from/to there. Try looking at `writeUTF(String)` for writing text, and `getFilePointer()` for remembering position in the file. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to "insert" text as you would do it in an editor, instead the contents are always "overwritten".

Also, `FileWriter` and `FileOutputStream` support append-mode, which you can use for appending extra data to the end of the file without rewriting it. But if you need to change things in the middle, you have to use random access file.

Answer (score 0):

check out the [**scanner class**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

it makes it easier to read and parse strings and primitive types using regular expressions.